# Trying to get a random quote from a php mysql, using flutter http

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and php, and am trying to get my flutter app to display a random quote generated on a php file. This php file in turn gets it's quote from a mysql db(will have about 200 entries). On the php front, the quote appears and everything seems to work fine (except that it's displayed with [[]] but if got it right it's because I'm calling objects,instead of strings?).

The problem is on the flutter side. I get the quote to appear on the screen as well as print, but it doesn't change to another quote if I press the floatingActionButton button. Unless I reload my php file in a browser.
My guess is that I'm storing an existing php string instead of calling for a new http request. But I don't know how to correct it.

PS. I've taken the code related to color out for better readability

```
//*****myphppage.php code:

$makeQuery = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$statement = $connection->prepare($makeQuery);
$statement->execute();
//stored in array bc originally had more quotes;
$myarray = array();
while ($resultsFrom = $statement ->fetch()){
    array_push(
       $myarray,array(
        $resultsFrom['body']
       )
      );
}
echo json_encode($myarray);

//////*******main.dart:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'about_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(Ojogo());

class Ojogo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Quote app',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Imperator',
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class Quote {
  final String quote;
  Quote.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : quote = json['body'];
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
....
  Future<void> getQuote() async {
    String theUrl = 'http://mywebsite.com/myphppage.php';
    http.Response response = await http.get(theUrl);
    var myQuote = jsonDecode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      _quote = myQuote.toString();
      print(_quote);
    });
  }

  void _getNewQuote() {
    setState(() {
      _quote = null;
    });
    getQuote();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getQuote();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orange,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [_colorOne, _colorTwo]), //take the gradients out
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0),
                        child: Text('QUOTE APP'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: IconButton(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite,
                            color: Colors.white),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => AboutScreen()));
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: _quote != null
                        ? Text('$_quote',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 34.0,
                              height: 1.25,
                            ))
                        : CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _getNewQuote, child: Icon(Icons.refresh)),
    );
  }
}
```

I'd like my flutter dart file to renew the quote everytime I press floatingActionButton:
Right now it does not refresh with new quote, unless I refresh the php page on a browser.

Comment: Any errors showing anywhere? What's the request's response? BTW, you could just encode what's returned from `->fetch()`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, no errors, it builds and install perfectly. As for fetch() how do I encode?

Comment: the request gives the quote. the problem is that if I press the floatingActionButton it does not give a new quote. On a browser though if I refresh, it refreshes the quote as requested.